# R: correlation function for independent samples

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

In R we have the function `cor.test` for paired samples, that tests whether two vectors (paired samples) are uncorrelated using Pearson's product moment correlation coefficient.

Is there in R an implementation of a correlation function for unpaired (independent) samples?

Thank you

Comment: A correlation of unpaired samples does not make any sense, as correlation tests whether the paired deviation from the mean is significant different from zero. How should a correlation of unpaired samples work? How would you even sort the vectors? And what could you hope to learn from it?

Comment: It would make sense in the t-test sense (same group, different treatment, rather than two different groups). Anyway, what is the difference between cor and cor.test in R?

Comment: `cor.test()` computes a test (Fishers' Z, if I'm not mistaken) to determine whether the correlation is significantly different from 0. `cor()` just computes the pearson product moment correlation (or others, if so specified). In T-Tests it makes sense to have independent samples as you then just compare the means. But with correlation you don't just compare one parameter of the distribution but the pairwise deviance from their relative means. That's a different way to look at the data.

Comment: Thanks, all clear. Now, I did not understand what the difference between cor.test() and cor() is. Shouldn't they give identical results while relying on different methods?

Comment: They use the exatly same methods. But `cor.test()` also includes a test of significance to determine whether the correlation is different from a test value (default: 0). The correlation coefficient they return is exactly the same.